# How Do I Trigger Adaptive/Maskable Icon for PWA in Android Task Switcher

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps

## Background

I'm trying to convert a web app into a true PWA. The only thing I haven't been able to get working is the adaptive icon in the Android Task Switcher view. Adaptive icon works perfectly in the app drawer:

[image]

However, it doesn't work in the task switcher:

[image]

My manifest code is:

```
{
    "name": "Kepler",
    "short_name": "Kepler",
    "theme_color": "rgb(30,130,230)",
    "background_color": "rgb(45,45,45)",
    "display": "standalone",
    "start_url": "/",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "https://hosted.functionaldevices.com/assets/kepler/favicons/android-chrome-72x72.png",
            "sizes": "72x72",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable any"
        },
        {
            "src": "https://hosted.functionaldevices.com/assets/kepler/favicons/android-chrome-96x96.png",
            "sizes": "96x96",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable any"
        },
        {
            "src": "https://hosted.functionaldevices.com/assets/kepler/favicons/android-chrome-128x128.png",
            "sizes": "128x128",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable any"
        },
        {
            "src": "https://hosted.functionaldevices.com/assets/kepler/favicons/android-chrome-144x144.png",
            "sizes": "144x144",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable any"
        },
        {
            "src": "https://hosted.functionaldevices.com/assets/kepler/favicons/android-chrome-152x152.png",
            "sizes": "152x152",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable any"
        },
        {
            "src": "https://hosted.functionaldevices.com/assets/kepler/favicons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable any"
        },
        {
            "src": "https://hosted.functionaldevices.com/assets/kepler/favicons/android-chrome-384x384.png",
            "sizes": "384x384",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable any"
        },
        {
            "src": "https://hosted.functionaldevices.com/assets/kepler/favicons/android-chrome-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png",
            "purpose": "maskable any"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is likely a bug in the app switcher and not something you can fix. You could report a bug to Android though.

Comment: I think this may be a Chrome (WebAPK) but, not Android, since it doesn't affect native Android apps. I've filed a bug with Chrome: https://crbug.com/1098580.

Comment: I'm also having this issue at the moment. I haven't found a solution for it yet and the bug report in Chromium hasn't been updated since November.